# Change a button color when textinput is null, by using onPress

Tags: react-native, button, colors, styles, onpress

I just started to learn React Native technology, so i try to change some lines in tutorial code. This is a form, which add new title, but I want to change color of button if value === "". I try to find, but mostly examples use classes, in this project I want to use functions

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { View, StyleSheet, TextInput, Button, Alert } from 'react-native'

export const AddTodo = ({ onSubmit }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('')

  const pressHandler = () => {
    if (value.trim()) {
      onSubmit(value)
      setValue('')
    } else {

      }
    }


  return (
    <View style={styles.block}>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={setValue}
        value={value}
        disabled
        placeholder='Введите название дела...'
        autoCorrect={false}
        autoCapitalize='none'
      />
      <Button title='Добавить' onPress={pressHandler} /> 
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  block: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom: 15
  },
  input: {
    width: '70%',
    padding: 10,
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    borderBottomColor: '#3949ab'
  },
  button: {
    color: 'red'
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a controlled input field. You store the value in your state and you change it onChange with the input field. Next step is to set a style for your button depending on your current state.

```
<TextInput
    style={[styles.input, value === '' ? styles.red : null]}
    onChangeText={setValue}
    value={value}
    disabled
    placeholder='Введите название дела...'
    autoCorrect={false}
    autoCapitalize='none'
  />
```

In this case you need to add a style called "red" which changes the button color.

```
red: {
  backgroundColor: 'red'
}
```

Something like this.

Because your state is updated every time you change the input value, it gets updated onChange. If you want to set it on submit you need to add a isSubmitted boolean (default false ) to your state and set it to true in your pressHandler.
You need to destructure isSubmitted in this example:

```
style={[styles.input, value === '' && isSubmitted ? styles.red : null]}
```

Comment: Thank you, maybe I did not explain my question clear. I needed to change a button, so finally I decided to make this 

`<Button disabled={value === '' && onSubmit ? true : false} title='Добавить' onPress={pressHandler} />`

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a simple logic as below

```
<Button
    title="Добавить"
    onPress={pressHandler}
    color={value === null ? 'red' : 'green'}
/>
```

**EDIT**

Check below sample which I created according to your requirement

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';

export default App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const [error, handleError] = useState(false);

  const pressHandler = () => {
    if (value.trim()) {
      setValue('');
    } else {
      handleError(true);
    }
  };

  const onHandleChange = (text) => {
    setValue(text)
    handleError(false)
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.block}>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={onHandleChange}
        value={value}
        placeholder="Введите название дела..."
        autoCorrect={false}
        autoCapitalize="none"
      />
      <Button
        title="Добавить"
        onPress={pressHandler}
        color={error ? 'red' : 'green'}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  block: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom: 15,
  },
  input: {
    width: '70%',
    padding: 10,
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    borderBottomColor: '#3949ab',
  }
});
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: Thank you, I just interchange red and green and this worked, but not how I thought, but I like this decision

Comment: @IlyaKraevoy If you could describe your question a bit. I might be able to help you with that.

Comment: You are very sympathetic, so I try to explain. I want that the button change color only on function onPress, than mean. If input === ' ', and I press the button, it must change color. In other words if input has no symbols, in this case, button change color.  P.S But your previos code is very good, it is nice, when button change color at the entering moment

Comment: @IlyaKraevoy Did you manage to make it work or do you need extra help?

Comment: Your advice is too enough for this moment, now I will put the theory into practice, and this was a step to more understand state principles. Thank you

Comment: @IlyaKraevoy If this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it.